# Javascript Basic animation problems

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to use pure JavaScript to animate a **plus sign** (+) but moving it up, when a button is clicked.

When the button is clicked, the plus sign moves up for about 100px and the animation ends. I would like to make it so that when the animation ends, another function brings back the plus sign back to its original position so that if the button is clicked again, the animation replies.

I cannot use jQuery for this, otherwise it would have been so much easier.

```js
cool.onclick = function() {
  let start = Date.now();

  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    let timePassed = Date.now() - start;

    train.style.top = timePassed / -3 + 'px';

    if (timePassed > 300) clearInterval(timer);


  }, 1);

  /////////////////
  //code to return the + sign back to its original position fayded
  ////////////////
}
```

```css
#train {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cool {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:200px; width:100%;"></div>
<div id="cool">BUTTON</div>
<div id="train">+</div>
```

Comment: CSS 3 animation is a option for you?

Comment: `train.style.top` set this value back to the one it is at the beginning?

Comment: @Valentin I guess it is, because it's hard to have no CSS support in a browser.

Comment: @Jeremy, same goes for JQuery.

Comment: Can I kindly ask for an example? if I style it in css, then after the function is Triggered, wouldnt the css be on override by the js? I've tried this  train.style.top = timePassed / +3 + 'px'; but its nto wokring

Comment: You might want to use `transform: translateY(0px);` instead so that animations are GPU accelerated.

Comment: @Mark OP can't use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the way to do it is with CSS.  Use the translateY animation.  But if you are really wanting to do it with Javascript, your code would look more like this:

```
<script>
    var PositionOffset = 0;
    var PositionIncrement = 1;
    var timer;
    cool.onclick = function() {
        train = document.getElementById("train");
        PositionIncrement = 1;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            PositionOffset = PositionOffset + PositionIncrement;
            train.style.top = PositionOffset + 'px';
            if (PositionOffset >= 100) {
                PositionIncrement = -1;
            }
            if (PositionIncrement == -1 && PositionOffset <= 0) {
                PositionOffset = 0;
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 10);
        timer.Start();
    }
</script>
```

Notice, this code moves it both up and down, by changing the increment to +1 when the button is clicked (at the start of the onclick function), and to -1 when the widget reaches the top, then stopping the timer when the position is on its way down (increment is -1) and the position offset reaches zero.

Notice that when the user clicks the button, even if the + sign is halfway up or already coming back down, it will start going back up again.  Reach the top, and head back down.

I've set the interval to 10 milliseconds, that means that by incrementing the position by 1 pixel on each tick of the timer, it will go up 100 pixels in 1 second (100px * 10msec/px = 1 sec).  If you want the animation to go faster or slower, just change that interval time.

Also, you were trying to use some variable called `train` in `train.style.top = ...`, but you never set that.  You can use javascript to get at the div that has that id, by just simply calling `document.getElementById`.

You may have other issues, (like, in order for changing the top to work, you have to set the style of your train div to have absolute position), but this should get you closer.

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gilmunoz/qvs7m0nj/4/).